# How to display the last third and forth photos with `@photo.last()`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my user profile, I want to add 4 of the latest photos uploaded by that user. Originally, I had `<%- @user.photos.last(4).each do |photo| %>`. This code works, but it doesn't work with my layout. So I need one row that displays the last 2 photos, while the second row displays the last 3-4 photos.

Here is what I came up with and the line `<%- @user.photos.last(3,4).each do |photo| %>` does not work. I've also tried `(3-4)`

```
<div class="photo-box">
  <%- @user.photos.last(2).each do |photo| %>
    <a href="<%= user_photo_path(@user.username, photo.id) %>" class="photo-thumbnail">
      <div class="photo-mini">
        <%= image_tag photo.url %>
      </div>
    </a>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="photo-box">
  <%- @user.photos.last(3,4).each do |photo| %>
    <a href="<%= user_photo_path(@user.username, photo.id) %>" class="photo-thumbnail">
      <div class="photo-mini">
        <%= image_tag photo.url %>
      </div>
    </a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[]` method on the `photos` array.

`-1` gets the last element, `-2` gets the 2nd to last, and so on.

```
 @user.photos[-2..-1].each #=> return the last two pictures
```

Of course, you can simply use the `@user.photos.last(2).each` in this case.

```
 @user.photos[-4..-3].each #=> return the last 3-4 pictures.
```

This will throw an error unless `@user.photos` has a length of at least 4, otherwise, you will be trying to access values that does not exist. So, to check for that, you can wrap the `div` in an `if` statement.

```
<% if @user.photos.length >= 2 %>
  <div class="photo-box">
    <% @user.photos.last(2).each do |photo| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if @user.photos.length >= 4 %>
  <div class="photo-box">
    <% @user.photos[-4..-3].each do |photo| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get an error for users that don't have 4 photos. How could I write an if statement that says `if user has 4 photos`. I am new to ruby and learning

Comment: please elaborate on what do you want to display in cases where user has 1, 2, and 3 photos?

Comment: what about if user only have 1 or 3 pictures?

Comment: If user has 2 photos. Show the first row. If the user has 4 photos, show the second row also. If the user has less that 2, show no photos

Answer (score 1):

I would get the last four in an array, and then divide them into two sets of two using [#in_groups_of](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of).

You can then iterate through the two arrays of two photos each to create the divs. This methods easily extends to n groups of m photos.

Something like:

```
<%- @user.photos.last(4).in_groups_of(2, false).each do |photo_group| %>
  <div class="photo-box">
    <%- photo_group.each do |photo| %>
      <a href="<%= user_photo_path(@user.username, photo.id) %>" class="photo-thumbnail">
        <div class="photo-mini">
          <%= image_tag photo.url %>
        </div>
      </a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but I like this answer better, it's both more concise, and more easily adjusted to new layouts.